# Find the norm of the operator $A:L^{1}[1,2]\xrightarrow{} L^{1}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Find the norm of the operator $A:L^{1}[1,2]\xrightarrow{} L^{1}[0,1]$ such that $Af(x)=\int^{2}_{1}\frac{f(t)}{x+t}dt$.
I have been doing some exercises to get myself used to calculate norms. Regarding calculating norms of functionals I don't have any problem, but I am a little confused in how to proceed with the norm of an operator. Should I proceed with something like this?
$$\|Af\|_{1}=\int^{1}_{0}\Biggl|\int^{2}_{1}\frac{f(t)}{x+t}dt\Biggl|dx.$$
Or how should I compute this?

Comment: I typically try to compute the norm for an easy function to get a feel for how good of a bound I need. In this case, I'd try $f(t)=1$.

Comment: This looks like one would like to interchange the order of integration (as we then directly get a term which almost looks like the $L^1$ norm, i.e. I'd pull the absolute value inside and change the order of integration. Side note, it should be $dx$, not $ds$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ill try to compute the norm

Comment: Your operator does not really make sense. You are integrating $f$ over the interval $[1,2]$, however, $f$ is only defined on $[0,1]$. Should the domain be $L^1([1,2])$?

Comment: Yes, im sorry I missed typed, it should be in the interval [1,2], I will edit the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that the domain should be $A:L^1([1,2])\rightarrow L^1([0,1])$, otherwise the operator is not defined.

We have (using Fubini's theorem to change the order of integration)

\begin{align*}
\Vert Af\Vert_{L^1([0,1])}
&=\int_0^1 \left\vert \int_1^2 \frac{f(t)}{x+t} dt \right\vert dx 
\\
&\leq \int_0^1 \int_1^2 \left\vert \frac{f(t)}{x+t}\right\vert dt dx
\\
&=\int_1^2 \vert f(t)\vert \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+t} dx \right) \\
&= \int_1^2 \vert f(t)\vert \left(\ln(t+1)-\ln(t)\right) dt\\
&=\int_1^2 \vert f(t)\vert \ln(1+1/t) dt \\ 
&\leq \ln(2) \int_1^2 \vert f(t)\vert dt \\
&=\ln(2)\Vert f\Vert_{L^1([1,2])}.
\end{align*}
This implies $\Vert A\Vert \leq \ln(2)$.

Now if we stare at our computations for a moment, we realize that for $f\geq 0$ we get

\begin{align*}
\Vert Af\Vert_{L^1([0,1])}=\int_1^2 \ln(1+1/t) f(t)dt.
\end{align*}

In order to make this large, we need to pick $f$ in such a fashion that it is only supported close to $t=1$. A possible candidate is
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n,& x\in [1,1+1/n], \\ 0,& x\in (1+1/n,2].\end{cases} $$

Note that $\Vert f_n\Vert_{L^1([1,2])}=1$. Thus, we have
$$\Vert A\Vert \geq \Vert Af_n\Vert_{L^1([0,1])}=\frac{1}{n} \int_1^{1+1/n} \ln(1+1/t)dt.$$
Now use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get $\Vert A\Vert\geq \ln(2)$ and conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your comment also was super helpful as I managed to almost finish by my own, though I got stucked again till I saw your response.

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope I managed to get the intuition across. The choice of $f_n$ is convenient as we want to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, which is probably not the first thing that comes to once mind.

Comment: Yes it was super insightful, now I know how and what to look for :)

Comment: Final remark. I just saw that you changed the space to $L^1([1,2])$. One could do the same computation as I did above for that case and would just get a different value inside of the natural logarithm.

Comment: Perfect, with your response I am sure I can do it with the edit I made, though just for consistency sake I will edit the post so it coincides with your response.

Answer (score 2):

In general if $$Af(x)=\int\limits_c^dK(x,t)f(t)\,dt$$ where $K(x,t)\ge 0$ is continuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ then $$\|A\|=\max_{c\le t\le d}\int\limits_a^bK(x,t)\,dx$$
Indeed let $k(t)=\int\limits_a^bK(x,t)\,dx.$ Then $k$ is continuous and
$$\|Af\|_1=\int\limits_a^b\left |\int\limits_c^dK(x,t)f(t)\,dt\right |\,dx\\ \le
\int\limits_a^b\int\limits_c^dK(x,t)|f(t)|\,dt\,dx=
\int\limits_c^d|f(t)|k(t)\,dt\\
\le \max_{c\le t\le d}k(t)\,\|f\|_1$$
Moreover if $f\ge 0$ then
$$\|Af\|_1=\int\limits_c^df(t)k(t)\,dt$$
By the duality between $L^1(c,d)$ and $
L^\infty(c,d)$ we get
$$\|A\|=\sup_{f\ge 0,\,\|f\|_1\le 1}\int\limits_c^df(t)k(t)\,dt=\max_{c\le t\le d}k(t)$$
In the OP case we have $[a,b]=[0,1],$ $[c,d]=[1,2]$ and $K(x,t)=(x+t)^{-1}.$ Then
$$k(t)=\int\limits_0^1(t+x)^{-1}\,dx=\log(t+1)-\log t=\log(1+t^{-1})$$ Thus $\displaystyle\max_{1\le t\le 2}k(t)=\log 2.$